# MSBUILD fails from tasks.json yet works from from VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a build task in tasks.json of C# .net-core project under VS Code 1.32.3. If I run the task within tasks.json, it fails with MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: --run-time linux-arm

```
Executing task: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish --runtime linux-arm --configuration Debug --self-contained false M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode/HelloWorldVSCode.csproj <

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.385-preview+g966cdf2ac6 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: --runtime linux-arm
```

If I copy and paste the same command to VS Code terminal it works! Where is the error in the --runtime switch?

```
PS M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode> dotnet.exe publish --runtime linux-arm --configuration Debug --self-contained false M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode/HelloWorldVSCode.csprojMicrosoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.385-preview+g966cdf2ac6 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 25.18 ms for M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode\HelloWorldVSCode.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview-010184\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(151,5): message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview [M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode\HelloWorldVSCode.csproj]
  HelloWorldVSCode -> M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\linux-arm\HelloWorldVSCode.dll
  HelloWorldVSCode -> M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\linux-arm\publish\
PS M:\ProjectsGit\HelloWorldVSCode>
```

Comment: I don't have a fix for you, I just came here to say that I'm experiencing the same problem, except with the --configuration switch. Works fine from terminal/prompt but not from tasks.json :/

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to separate your arguments at spaces. Instead of:

```
"args": [
   "publish",
   "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorldVSCode/HelloWorldVSCode.csproj",
   "--runtime linux-arm",
   "--configuration Debug",
   "--self-contained",
],
```

Try something like this instead:

```
"args": [
   "publish",
   "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorldVSCode/HelloWorldVSCode.csproj",
   "--runtime",
   "linux-arm",
   "--configuration",
   "Debug",
   "--self-contained",
   "false",
],
```

The args list here doesn't take well to spaces. Alternatively, you can make use of the fact that the dotnet CLI tolerates using `=` as well, so the following should also work:

```
"args": [
   "publish",
   "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorldVSCode/HelloWorldVSCode.csproj",
   "--runtime=linux-arm",
   "--configuration=Debug",
   "--self-contained=false",
],
```

Comment: this behavior is really very strange to me - but it... works. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯
many thanks

Comment: Oh man I searched for so long - thanks!